# Problems trying to combine lists in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

As an exercise in learning Erlang, I'm trying to write a simple database (from O'Reilly's Programming Erlang).

Basically I have a list of Tuples like this:

```
Db1 = [{person1,charleston},{person2,charleston},{person3,chicago}].
```

I need to create function such that

```
db:match(charleston,Db1).
```

returns

```
[person1,person2]
```

Here's the method that I wrote:

```
match(Element, Db) -> match(Element, Db, []).
match(_Element,[], Results) -> Results;
match(Element, [{Key,Value}|T], Results) ->
    case Value == Element of
        true -> match(Element, T, [Results,Key]);
        false -> match(Element,T,Results)
    end.
```

The result I'm getting back is this:

```
[[[],person1],person2]
```

I know there are ways of combining lists with the `lists.erl` module, but I'm trying to bypass it in an effort to learn more about the language. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your `case Value == Element` can be folded into the clause: `match(Value, [{Key, Value}|T], ...) ->` and so on.

Comment: And your case is so simple I wouldn't use a tail recursive accumulator here, but rather use `[Key|match(Element, T)]` as a recurser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is how you are building up your list, try this instead:

```
case Value == Element of
    true -> match(Element, T, [Key|Results]);
    false -> match(Element,T,Results)
end.
```

- [A,B] builds a new list with elements A and B.
- [A|B] prepends A to the list B.

Comment: This is the problem of the original code. And that you swap `Key` and `Results`.

Comment: Why is [Key|Results] different then [Results|Key]. I thought the latter part was appended to the first part. No?

Comment: `Key` is a value while `Results` is a list of values. The `[_|_]` construct is normally used in the way of `[Value|ListofValues]` to **prepend** the first part to the second part. Using it in the reverse order is legal but it is not the normal way of working with lists and there is no support for this. Appending a value to a list is another much less efficient operation which is generally avoided if possible.

Comment: @rvirding so as a side-effect then this would actually wind up building a reversed list right?

Comment: @Micah yes as you are in effect *pushing* the elements on to a list/stack which you then return.

Answer (score 7):

You're re-inventing the wheel.  Just use [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html):

```
match(X, Db) -> [P || {P, E} <- Db, E == X].
```

Comment: Even shorter with pattern matching: match(X, Db) -> [P || {P, X} <- Db].

Comment: @hdima That solution doesn't work because X in the List Comprehensions generator will shadow the match/2 argument X.

Comment: Only reason I didn't mark this as the answer is that I haven't done anything with pattern matching yet and was looking for specifically a recursion solution. But great answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to write the code directly is

```
match(_Value, []) -> [];
match(Value, [{Key,Value}|T]) ->
    [Key|match(Value, T)];
match(Value, [_|T]) ->
    match(Value, T).
```

The *list comprehension* in @Little Bobby Tables solution is equivalent to this.

Comment: It doesn't look like your last match/3 ever gets called. All calls to match are for match/2.